# Как сделать так, чтобы QColorDialog открывался всегда поверх MainWindow?

Tags: c++, qt

Я вызываю `QColorDialog` примерно так:

```
QColor color = QColorDialog::getColor(rectangle->getColor(),this,"Chose Color");
```

При этом флаг `Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint` не помог, `raise` тоже.

Как мне сделать так, чтобы `QColorDialog` был всегда поверх уже открытых окон (первый раз он находится поверх MainWindow, а вот со второго раза всё плохо, он открывается за MainWindow)?

Парент = this тоже не помог.

`rectangle` - самописный Shape (адаптер) - указатель на него, `getColor` - функция, возвращающая `QColor`

Comment: Покажите, с какими параметрами вызывается `getColor`. У меня диалог открылся поверх всех окон. Еще из вариантов можно попробовать передать в конструктор указатель на родителя (подозреваю, что `this`)